# 二つの配列A,B

Tags: array

C言語についての質問です。
二つの配列A,Bがありそれぞれに整数が格納されていて、配列の中の数は昇順にソートされていて、配列Aの中には重複する数がなく、それは配列Bについても一緒である。
ただし、配列AとBのサイズは同じとは限らない。

それを踏まえて配列AとBの中には重複する数があり、その重複して含まれる数を出力するプログラムを教えてください

Comment: 二重ループしたらいかが？配列Aをforか何かで回して、各項目をBの全項目と比較してやれば所望の処理になると思いますよ。

Comment: [print common elements from two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810676/print-common-elements-from-two-arrays)

Comment: user30429 さんと同じ方の別アカウントと推察します。コメントを読んで(かどうかわかりませんが)質問内容を改善しようとしてくださっているのは良いことなのですが、アカウントを複数作成してしまったせいで、ご自分の質問なのに編集に承認が要る状態となっているようです。アカウントの統合については、こちらのヘルプトピック「[間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)」をご参照ください。重複投稿の片方をクローズしてもらうようにしてもらった方が良いでしょう。慣れないと戸惑うことが多いかもしれませんが、マナーも守った上でこのサイトの機能をうまく利用すること(「編集」やら「コメント」やら)がご自身の問題を早く解決する近道にもなります。

Comment: 皆さんありがとうございます！アカウントが二つできていましたすみません

Comment: @user30430 さん、アカウントが２つできていたとのことでしたので、アカウントを統合し、[古い方のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/49089/19110)をご利用ください。こちらの質問は質問の重複として印をつけさせて頂きました。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。